# if a group have boys and girls is correct to say "all the boys"

Tags: word-usage, usage

If we have a group with both boys and girls, is it right  to use "all the boys"?

In particular, is it right to take "that" as gender neutral when I made a translation  in to Spanish?

Comment: To clarify, by "boys" and "girls" are you referring to children, or to males and females of any age? *Boy* is unambiguously male, but some terms like *guy* and *buddy* are at least significantly less gendered now than they were a generation ago.

Answer (score 2):

"All the boys" would make people assume all of the young people you are referring to are male, so it is not an appropriate gender neutral term to group boys and girls.

It would be better to say "all the children" or "all the kids" (less formal), assuming the people referred to are fairly young. Gender neutral terms for older youth are a bit trickier and depend on context.

Comment: That was i think, but some one make me doubt about that.

Comment: This answer is correct. It's tricky when translating into Spanish because 'hijos' can be neutral or boys only.